# Leap year calculator assignment

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm using Python to make a calculator for leap years. Through several corrections, something was still missing and I ended up using Thonny.
The program told me to change everything from `else` to `elif`, but gives me a syntax error for the colon like this:

```python
year = int(input("Which year do you want to check? "))

if year % 4 == 0:
    if year % 100 == 0:
        if year % 400 == 0:
            print("Leap year")
        elif: 
            print("Not a leap year")
    elif: 
        print("Leap year")
elif: year % 4 /= 0:
    print("Not a leap year")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/op108/Leap year calc.py", line 6
    elif:
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: `elif: year % 4 /= 0:` is not working python code. First Problem: no colon after `elif`. Second problem `/=` does not mean *not equal* in python.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is caused by the Python's keyword `elif`.

```
if (condition):
    ...
elif (condition):
    ...
else:
    ...
```

You can't use the keyword `elif` without specifying a condition after it, and if you do it you shouldn't put `:` between `elif` and its condition.

---

An other error in your code is caused by `/=` operator, that in Python isn't the contrary of `==`: did you mean `!=`?

---

In your case:

```
if year % 4 == 0:
    if year % 100 == 0:
        if year % 400 == 0:
            print("Leap year")
        else: 
            print("Not a leap year")
    else: 
        print("Leap year")
else:
    print("Not a leap year")
```

---

I would suggest to write it using `or` and `and` in conditions instead of all these nested `if`s:

```
if (year%4 == 0 and (year%100 != 0 or year%400 == 0)):
    print("Leap year")
else:
    print("Not a leap year")
```

Comment: This isn't [ternary](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html).

Comment: You are right, I had a wrong memory coming by a famous SO question, I'm editing the answer :)

Comment: I think the sentence: `You can't use the keyword elif without specifying a condition after it.` is a bit out of place -  I don't see the connection to the question. As I see it, OP tried to specify a condition, but failed due to an extra colon. The fact that the whole clause can be substituted by an `else` clause is a different thing (and IMO should be explained seperately).

Answer (score 0):

On line 6 (and line 8 as well), you need to use `else` instead of `elif`, since you are not checking an additional conditional. `elif` is appropriate on line 10 (since you are checking another condition), but you have a syntax problem there as well (see the comment on `/=`).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is arising due to the `elif` on lines 6 and 8. You must specify a condition when you are using `elif`. In your case, you should use `else` instead of `elif` on lines 6 and 8 as follows:

```py
year = int(input("Which year do you want to check? "))
if year % 4 == 0:
    if year % 100 == 0:
        if year % 400 == 0:
            print("Leap year")
        else: 
            print("Not a leap year")
    else: 
        print("Leap year")
elif year % 4 != 0:
    print("Not a leap year")
```

Also, on line 10 your syntax is wrong, where you should use `!=` instead of `/=`. However, this an overkill and you really should just use `else` on line 10 as well, as you have already checked the opposite condition in line 2.